# Is there anyway to override class from other module while keeping it's methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, composition

In order to illustrate my question, here are 3 modules :

This is the module A

```
'''
lets call this module the parent, it regroups multiple classes with several
method each
'''

class Rectangle():
    '''
    The basic rectangle class that is parent for other classes in this
    module
    '''
    def __init__(self, x_length, y_length):
        self.x_length = x_length
        self.y_length = y_length

    def create_points(self):
        '''
        Basic geometrical method 
        '''
        self.point_1 = [x_length/2, y_length/2]
        self.point_2 = [-x_length/2, y_length/2]
        self.point_3 = [-x_length/2, -y_length/2]
        self.point_4 = [x_length/2, -y_length/2]

class Square(Rectangle):
    '''
    The square that is a rectangle with two identical sides
    '''
    def __init__(self, side_dim):
        super().__init__(side_dim, side_dim)

class SquareCollection():
    '''
    Creates a composition relation with an other class of the module
    '''
    def __init__(self, dim_list):
        '''
        The constructor creates a square for every float in the given list
        '''
        for val in dim_list:
            try:
                self.element.append(Square(val))
            except AttributeError:
                self.element = [Square(val)]

    def create_points(self):
        for elmt in self.element:
            elmt.create_points()
```

This is the Module B1

```
'''
lets call this module the child 1, it redefines the classes from the parent but
with an additionnal method specific for its use case
'''
import Module_A as ma

class Rectangle(ma.Rectangle):
    '''
    The basic rectangle class that is parent for other classes in this
    module
    '''
    def module_specific_method(self):
        self.special_attribute_1 = True

class Square(ma.Square):
    '''
    The square that is a rectangle with two identical sides
    '''
    def module_specific_method(self):
        self.special_attribute_1 = True

class SquareCollection(ma.SquareCollection):
    '''
    Redefining the SquareCollection with an additionnal method
    '''
    def module_specific_method(self):
        for elmt in self.element:
            elmt.module_specific_method()
```

And this is the module B2

```
'''
lets call this module the child 2, it redefines the classes from the parent but
with an additionnal method specific for its use case
This module is a copy of Module_B2 and is used to justify the used code
structure
'''
import Module_A as ma

class Rectangle(ma.Rectangle):
    '''
    The basic rectangle class that is parent for other classes in this
    module
    '''
    def module_specific_method(self):
        self.special_attribute_2 = True

class Square(ma.Square):
    '''
    The square that is a rectangle with two identical sides
    '''
    def module_specific_method(self):
        self.special_attribute_2 = True

class SquareCollection(ma.SquareCollection):
    '''
    Redefining the SquareCollection with an additionnal method
    '''
    def module_specific_method(self):
        for elmt in self.element:
            elmt.module_specific_method()
```

When I import the module B2 create a `sc = SquareCollection([4, 3.5, 0.8])` instance and then run `sc.module_specific_method()` I get an `AttributeError` for the called `Square` classes that are created using the A module because the `SquareCollection` class inherits from the one defined in the A module which itself creates multiple `Square` instances based on the class defined in the same module. The `AttributeError` is expected because nowhere in the A module I am defining this `module_specific_method`.

Due to the structure of my code and how I am currently using it, I am using either module B1 or module B2. I currently avoid this issue by rewriting everything contained in module A twice (one in B1 and the other in B2). Because I am refactoring all my code, I wish I could remove all code duplicate and put it in a "common" module as shown above with the simplified example.

How is it possible for classes in module A to inherit/point back to the B module from which I called it ?

I hope my issue is clear, because I really have a hard time formalizing it.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by making the `Square` class used in the base `SquareCollection` an attribute of the collection class, so that instead of being hardcoded it becomes explicitly overridable by subclasses, too:

```py
# Module_A
class Square:
    pass      # implement stuff here

class SquareCollection
    BaseItem = Square    # the "class that is collected here"

    def __init__(self, dim_list):
        # spawn BaseItem instances here, which are Square by default,
        # but might be set to something else in a subclass
        self.element = [self.BaseItem(val) for val in dim_list]
```

```py
# Module_B1
import Module_A as ma

class Square(ma.Square):
     pass

class SquareCollection(ma.SquareCollection):
    # override the collection's BaseItem with this module's Square class,
    # but keep the rest of the SquareCollection code the same
    BaseItem = Square
```